# Why does my user signup request have no response back?

Tags: users

I have a Drupal website hosted on a LAMP server (dev machine on intranet).

When tried to signup using the registration page (signup page for a user), the page keeps loading with message "waiting for server".

When tried to check using firebug add on in Firefox, I saw in the "network" tab that there is no response back for the signup request.

Does it have to do with the SMTP configuration within the server?

But once logging in  with admin and checking the "people" tab shows that the user is created but there was no email sent to verify the email address

So I believe the next step after user creation (according to code) gets failed due to which there is no response and email not sent. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

was able to resolve this. The problem was with the incorrect configuration of SMTP relay host which was blocking the sending email part while signing up, due to which the request was incomplete with no response. If anyone has the same problem it should probably be with the SMTP configuration settings on the server